# calculate column

Tags: calculated-column

I'm using SharePoint 2007, Custom list.

I have created calculate column.
in order to configure this column I need to insert the column name and to create a formula.

Is it possible to write a range of column that need to be included the formula?

**etc:** =SUM(the last 4 column from the current list from right to left)

**instead of:** =SUM([June],[July],[August],[September])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't give like that.
In SharePoint calculated column, we have to give individual column name to get the sum of all column values.

Ref: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/sum-function-HA001161076.aspx

Formulas and functions for calculated column, http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/CH010065006.aspx